# Need help with function parameters Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I'm really newbie developing iphone apps, and I got a question...

I would like to know how must I do to receive the var that my function returns.

Take a look:

```
-(void)myfunc{
     float num1 = 2.50;
     float num2 = 3.50;

     //here is my doubt, how can I get the value that function returns?
     float varreceived = [self getNumber:num1:num2];
}

//the function that receive the vars and returns a value 

-(float)getNumber: (float)var1 :(float)var2 {

        NSLog(@"1->%f",var1);
        NSLog(@"2->%f",var2);

        return 3.23;
}
```

I receive this error when I build:

"error: void value not ignored as it ought to be"

in this line:

float varreceived = [self getNumber:num1:num2];

***Update:***

Nop, I receive this error when I build:

> "error: void value not ignored as it ought to be"

in this line:

```
float varreceived = [self getNumber:num1:num2];
```

Max:

> then you probably declared the -(float)getNumber: (float)var1 :(float)var2 as -(void)getNumber: (float)var1 :(float)var2 in your header

HispaJavi:

> Yeah!! this is the problem, I wrote "-(void)getNumber" in header! I changed it "-(float)getNumber" and it works!! thanks!!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you NSLog the value of varRecieved after you set it, so we can see what happens to it?

Comment: Look, I edited it, I receive an error when I build...

Comment: As an FYI, these are methods, not functions.  Also, you really should give names to the arguments on your method, like the following: `- (float)getNumber:(float)firstNumber withOtherNumber:(float)secondNumber`.  It's standard Cocoa style to be as descriptive as possible when naming methods, so that your code is more readable later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK. You'll receive 3.23

Comment: Thank you, the problem was in the header ;)